# Problem with appending values into a empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (1995,2020):
  file_name = f"{i}"
  df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(uploaded["%s.csv"%file_name]))
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['DATE','ARANGALI'])
  frame.append(df)
print(frame)
```

I tried to define a function to append all the the data I have into one dataframe. The output appears to be an empty dataframe.

Empty DataFrame;
Columns: [];
Index: [].

The code works if consider the variables frame and df as lists and appends up to a large list. But I want a dataframe with all the data under the same column heads.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append method returns a new DataFrame. [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (1995,2020):
  file_name = f"{i}"
  df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(uploaded["%s.csv"%file_name]))
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['DATE','ARANGALI'])
  frame = frame.append(df)
print(frame)
```